# Нет доступа к Context внутри Fragment

Tags: java, android

У меня есть фрагмент, который реализует один интерфейс с одним методом.
Когда я в методе этого интерфейса пытаюсь обратиться к контексту - приложение падает с `NullPointerException`. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Object data) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             //do something
         }
     });
    }
}
```

Comment: скорей всего вызов метода `update` происходит раньше, чем фрагмент приатачился к активити

Answer (score 1):

А где вызывается `update` ? Видимо в этот момент состояние фрагмента невалидно (еще не прошел вызов `onAttach` например), нужны проверки и\или отложенный вызов. Если подходит, можно использовать контекст `Application` или брать из `onCreateView` у `container`